# my datepicker Jquery its out of css scope

Tags: jquery, html, css, datepicker

I have tried to play around with the calender on its own, and it works perfectly. [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/p7rtu/1/) but I dont understand why when i click on the calender when I put it in my code, the box become out of order. I cant figure out which line causes the box to become a mess.  i am using UI.all.css and bootstrap. they are both there in the link I have provided, the code for the datepicker is

```
<div class="well form-inline"> Original Image Date
    <form>
        <input id="date" class="span2" size="16" type="text"  readonly=""/>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.5.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#date").datepicker({ showOn: 'button', buttonImageOnly: true, buttonImage: 'http://beta.orbitelcom.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/icon_cal.jpg' });
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this css

```
.ui-datepicker-header select.ui-datepicker-new-month {
    height: auto;
}
.ui-datepicker-header select.ui-datepicker-new-year {
    height: auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p7rtu/2/

Comment: It works perfectly there, but Still its doesnt in my local computer

Comment: may be your  included other css files.in same file. that properties overriding . try to include jquery css file bottom of all css files. but i am not sure your problem is solved